# What happens if I invoke the `ExecuteReader` method on a `SqlCommand` referencing a stored procedure that returns no rowsets?

Tags: .net, ado.net, sqldatareader

I have a `SqlCommand` which may return zero or more rowsets. What happens if, by chance, the `SqlCommand` would return exactly zero rowsets* and I invoke its `ExecuteReader` method? Do I get a `SqlDataReader` that cannot be read, or do I get an exception?

Just in case: Zero rowsets is not the same thing as one rowset containing exactly zero rows.

Comment: The best way is to try yourself

Comment: @abatischev: Not really. The best way would be if documentation didn't suck, and actually explained what happens in these corner cases.

Comment: this isn't a corner/hedge case. If it were not common to retrun 0 records (or ROWSETS ;) ), then the SqlDataReader would return `null`.

Comment: @IAbstract: I never said a single rowset containing zero records. I said zero **ROWSETS**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `reader.FieldCount` will be zero for no rowset.  If you use a dataset instead of a reader, you will get a null dataset for no rowset.

Answer (score 1):

`SqlDataReader.Read()` as well as `HasRows` will return `false`:

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows) // false
{
    while (reader.Read()) // false
    {
        // will never reach
    }
}
```

Comment: @abatischev: So... how can I tell whether the stored procedure has returned zero rowsets, or one or more empty rowsets?

Comment: @Eduardo: Under empty rowset do you understand a row with a single nulled field? Or what?

Comment: @abatischev: `if 0 = 1 select 1` produces zero rowsets.

Comment: @abatischev: By contrast, `select 1 where 0 = 1` produces a single empty rowset.

Comment: @abatischev: And, when I tested `select null` on SQL Server Management Studio, it returned a rowset containing one row.

Answer (score 1):

You should still receive an SqlDataReader object. when you try:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand( /* params */))
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows)    // check to see if we have any rows
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // process
        }
    }
}
```

... you will simply 'fall through' as `Read()` will return `false`.